# How do I watch tested files with MochaJS?

Tags: javascript, testing, npm, mocha.js

I am testing the javascript that's sitting on top of my Rails app (using sprockets) with NPM (which is not connected to my Rails app in any way).

Everything is working great - the tests run (using NPM).

But how do I tell MochaJS which JavaScript files I want to test in my Rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found out one would need to use a task runner such as Gulp, Grunt, or Webpack along with MochaJS to watch the files being tested.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [konacha](https://github.com/jfirebaugh/konacha) gem which integrates mocha and chai in the rails workflow.

> Konacha ... is a Rails engine that allows you to test your JavaScript with the Mocha test framework and chai assertion library.
>
> It ... does not attempt to be framework agnostic. By sticking with Rails, Konacha can take full advantage of features such as the asset pipeline and engines.

It can be integrated with [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard/) through [guard-konacha](https://github.com/alexgb/guard-konacha) to watch for files and re-run tests.